# Is there a ValueTask<T> in C# 7.0?

Tags: async-await, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

There are a few preliminary sources that mention that there is a new ValueTask in C# 7.0:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

http://intellitect.com/generalized-async-return-types/

But I am not able to find this type?

Answer (score 25):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types), `System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>` is in the [`System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/).

Answer (score 2):

For those still struggling to use ValueTask, the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions Nuget package must still be installed. My system includes VS 2017 version 15.2 along with version 4.7 of the .NET Framework - and I still had to install the Nuget package.

To install the package, from VS 2017 click on the Project menu and select Manage Nuget Packages. In the search box, enter System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions and then install it. You should be good to go after this.